# Run VBA for all Excel but not through Project

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, macros

I want to run VBA on Excel files (a clean-up function) However, I want this to be available to certain users only.

Example would be to send the user a .bat file and tell them to save it and double click on this.

1. It would open VBA Macro
2. Macro will ask the user to choose the 'file' among all opened files to run macro which would be housed in a network location
3. Macro checks if user selected a valid Excel file, then runs

However, how would I go on to do this? I've done some research and read that I need to create VBS file.

Can someone please give me a right path to start? Should I write .batch to call VBS which will house the code?

Thanks!

Comment: You could either use VBScript, or you could just write it as VBA and send the user the .xlsm file containing the macro you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very brief module which does this kind of thing - principally the exporting/importing of modules as .bas files.

You need to enable the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility"  reference (mine is 5.3 - I'm not sure if there are different versions), but once you've done that it should work

```
Public Sub CopyModule(Workbook1 As Workbook, ModuleName As String, Workbook2 As Workbook)
''copies a named module between two workbooks VBA projects
''also acts as a backup as it saves a copy of the module as at today's date

'set name of exported module file
wbname = Workbook1.name & "." & ModuleName & "." & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")
Dim filename As String: filename = "H:\ASC\Reporting Files\CMT\" & wbname & ".bas"

'define module to be copied from book 1 based on input arguments
Dim CopyModule As VBComponent
Set CopyModule = Workbook1.VBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName)

'export module
CopyModule.Export (filename)

'import module into book 2
Workbook2.VBProject.VBComponents.Import (filename)

End Sub
```

The idea here was to copy the module between two workbooks that were already open, and also to back the module up at the same time. But you can treat the export/import lines as seperate routines and run them at different times. Hope this helps!

Comment: I've deleted this answer and undeleted it - I'm undecided on whether this is at all the sort of solution you're looking for - if not let me know and I'll re-delete